# AJAX is not passing variables to controller : Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I am using ajax to post variables for pagination in codeigniter.
This is my ajax function:

```
$("p.pagination a").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var start_row = url.split("/")[5];
    var pagination = true;

    $.ajax({
        statusCode : { 404: function(){alert('Not Found');} },
        type       : 'POST',
        data       : {start_row : start_row,pagination:pagination},
        url        : 'notification/all',
        success    : function(res){
                         alert(res);
                         $('#divClients').html(null);
                         $('#divClients').html(res);
                     }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Controller function:

```
function all($filter='all'){
    $start_row = isset($_POST['start_row'])?$_POST['start_row']:'';
}
```

I am not getting that start_row variable. AJAX ispassing this URL:

```
http://website.com/notification/all/10
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your js file is placed in your web server, can you try something like

```
url: '<?php echo site_url('notification/all')?>'
```